# Angular 4 Imgur image upload

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to upload an image to the Imgur API via Angular and am new to TypeScript and not sure how to start.

Currently I am getting the file from a file picker with the following code:

```
let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
let files: FileList = target.files;
let file: File = files[0];
```

Now I need to take `file` and put it into the body of a POST request to the Imgur API.

The URL for the request is `https://api.imgur.com/3/image` has headers of a authorization client ID, then a parameter in the body named `image` which is a binary file.

Can anyone show me how to write such a request with a callback?

https://apidocs.imgur.com/#4b8da0b3-3e73-13f0-d60b-2ff715e8394f

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question so I'll just hit the high points.  Come back when you run into a specific issue.

UPDATE:  I was looking into the `FormData` API a bit more and realized it will accept a `File` object so you can skip step 1 & 2.

1. Read the file.  Use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).  Since the API has nothing to do with the UI there is no Angular integration required.  You might use `RxJS-DOM` or `promise-file-reader` to integrate with either promises or observables (the native API is callback driven) but you can wrap it yourself pretty easily to.
2. Choose your format.  When #1 is done you should have an ArrayBuffer (native javascript object to represent a byte array).  You can either send that directly (imgur accepts binary data) or convert it into BASE64.  BASE64 is a way to represent binary arrays as ASCII data which can make for easier debugging and portability at the expense of using about 1.3x more bytes.
3. Submit the image to Imgur.  To make a simple HTTP request to Imgur you can use the Angular `Http` service which is pretty easy.  However, Imgur expects a multipart request (this is often seen when sending a binary payload along with some kind of request metadata) and that is a little more complicated.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731066/how-to-upload-filesmultipart-using-angularjs2) describes how to send a multipart request using the native `FormData` API and Angular's `Http` service.
4. In step 3 you will need to make sure your HTTP POST has the proper authorization headers.  You can do this by hand (you will notice a section creating the headers in the answer I linked in step 3.  It creates empty headers but you can supply your own).  From my glance at Imgur's documentation it appears you have two choices.  First, you can just supply a client ID for anonymous upload.  This is the easiest and I'd recommend it if that works for you.  If you need the image to be linked to a user account then you need to follow an OAuth 2.0 workflow in which case I'd recommend looking for a library that works with Angular.